# How to change the state of a bloc on another page in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two widgets in which I use the same `BLoC VehiclesCubit`. When I change the data in one widget, I need to refresh the page so that the data in the other widget is updated. But how to make it so that when the data in one widget changes, the second widget is automatically updated for someone who uses the same `BLoC`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, Let's make it simple
You have `VehiclesCubit` this cubit is initiated when you call

```
BlocProvider<VehiclesCubit>(
   create: (context) => VehiclesCubit()
)
```

You have `Widget1` and you created the `VehiclesCubit` in it, which mean the `widget1` contains the `VehiclesCubit` **context** in it.

Now, You have `Widget2` and you want to listen to the changes that happens in  `VehiclesCubit`, which means the `Widget2` should contain the  `VehiclesCubit` **context**

So How you can do this? by **injecting** the `VehiclesCubit` value to `widget2` with `BlocProvider.value` and just wrap it with `BlocConsumer<VehiclesCubit,VehiclesStates>`

**WidgetOne**

```
class WidgetOneScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => VehiclesCubit(),
      child: BlocConsumer<VehiclesCubit, VehiclesStates>(
        listener: (BuildContext context, VehiclesStates state) {},
        builder: (BuildContext context, VehiclesStates state) {
          final cubit = VehiclesCubit.get(context);
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
                    value: cubit,
                    child: WidgetTwo(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Item(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**WidgetTwo**

```
class WidgetTwoScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<VehiclesCubit,VehiclesStates>(
      listener: (BuildContext context, VehiclesStates state) {},
      builder: (BuildContext context,VehiclesStates state) {
        final cubit = VehiclesCubit.get(context);
        return Item();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I have a bloc and it is in two different files and I don't navigate to the second widget through navigation?

Comment: As we agreed 'the Widget2 should contain the VehiclesCubit context'. So, you can wrap your 'MaterialApp' with 'MultiBlocProvider' and now access it from anywhere in the app because the whole app contains the 'VehiclesCubit context'.