# Good way to mange state inside dialog with a form on it, being displayed from page with its own bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, bloc

See for the invoice page I have BlocBuilder wrapped in a scaffold of stateful page, inside that body under several widgets is a call to future void in separate file call to create a dialog widget. And inside the dialog method is a call to create an invoice form which is in a separate file and is stateful class displayed to be displayed on the dialog screen. In this form the user will be able to add and delete UI elements from a list view what I need to do is rebuild the widget either dialog screen/form or the list view/ to reflect the changes made by the user

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:developer' as dev;
import 'package:track/src/features/invoices/application/bloc.dart';
import 'package:track/src/features/invoices/application/events.dart';
import 'package:track/src/features/invoices/application/pdf_invoice_api.dart';

class InvoiceForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final InvoiceBlocController blocController;
  const InvoiceForm(this.blocController, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InvoiceForm> createState() => _InvoiceFormState();
}

class _InvoiceFormState extends State<InvoiceForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: TextEditingController()
              ..text = widget.blocController.invoice.client,
            validator: (value) {
              value!.isEmpty ? 'Enter a value for client' : null;
            },
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Client:',
                labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: TextEditingController()
              ..text =
                  '${widget.blocController.invoice.projectNumber}-${widget.blocController.invoice.invoiceNumber}',
            validator: (value) {
              value!.isEmpty ? 'Enter a valid project number' : null;
            },
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                labelText: 'Client:',
                labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: widget.blocController.invoice.items.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = widget.blocController.invoice.items[index];
              return ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                trailing: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      widget.blocController.add(DeleteItemFromInvoice(index));
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                title: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        itemTextFormField(
                            initialValue: item.name ?? '',
                            labelText: 'name',
                            index: index),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        itemTextFormField(
                            initialValue: item.description ?? '',
                            labelText: 'description',
                            index: index),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        itemTextFormField(
                            initialValue: item.quantity.toString(),
                            labelText: 'quantity',
                            index: index),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        itemTextFormField(
                            initialValue: item.costBeforeVAT.toString(),
                            labelText: 'Cost Before VAT',
                            index: index),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 30),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 2,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    dev.log('button clicked to add new item');
                    widget.blocController.add(AddNewItemToInvoice());
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    _formKey.currentState!.save();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    await PdfInvoiceApi.generate(widget.blocController.invoice);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send))
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Expanded itemTextFormField({
    required String initialValue,
    required String labelText,
    required int index,
  }) {
    return Expanded(
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: TextEditingController()..text = initialValue,
        onSaved: (newValue) {
          widget.blocController.add(UpdateInvoiceDetails(index));
        },
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          labelText: labelText,
          labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelMedium,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

InvoiceDialog Source code: https://pastebin.com/PCjmCWsk
InvoiceDialog Source code: https://pastebin.com/VS5CG22D
[image: InvoiceDialog]

Edit 2: Made the follwoing changes to bloc per Mostafa answer as best I could, getting pressed against a deadline here so really need some help:
These changes were to main page calling the show dialog passing bloc.

```dart
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
  value: blocController,
  child: InvoiceDetailsDialog(
  screenWidth: screenWidth,
  screenHeight: screenHeight),
  ),
);
```

This file was the original place where showdialog was called and was custom Future return showDialog.
Results: showDialog takes enitre screen. Rendering Invoice form reulsts in error being displayed in place of the form:

```dart
No Material widget found.
```

Edit 3: fixed previous error but back where i started bloc is still being called succesfully but no changes to the ui:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final blocController = BlocProvider.of<InvoiceBlocController>(context);
  return Center(
    child: Material(color: Colors.red,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: screenWidth / 2, height: screenHeight / 2,
        child: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(children: [
              Expanded(child: ListView(children: [
                    Text('Invoices',
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
                    InvoiceForm()
                  ]))])))));
}
```

As form nothing changed except instead of passing the blocController through a method I am now calling it like:

```dart
class _InvoiceFormState extends State<InvoiceForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  late final InvoiceBlocController blocController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    blocController = BlocProvider.of<InvoiceBlocController>(context);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Still nothing changes.

Edit 4: Set state does work and leaving in bloc code was executing and if I clicked add two items would be added or delete would remove two items. But with setstate commented out it went back to not rebuilding.  Using setstate for now but not preferred.

Edit 5: Don't if this is still being paid attention to hopefully is. Can I keep add add events like: add(NewItem), add(deleteItem),add(GeneratePDF). Without changing state. currently I have done that once so far. Is this bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the main bloc to the dialog widget and call the bloc function that you want and it will reflect on the main screen

How can you do this? by **injecting** the `MainBloc` value to `DialogWidget` with `BlocProvider.value`

**MainWidget**

```
class MainWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => MainBloc(),
      child: BlocConsumer<MainBloc, MainStates>(
        listener: (BuildContext context, MainStates state) {},
        builder: (BuildContext context, MainStates state) {
          final bloc = MainBloc.get(context);
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              showDialog(
                context,
                builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
                  value: bloc,
                  child: WidgetTwoDialog(),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Item(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**DialogWidget**

```
class DialogWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = MainBloc.get(context);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        bloc.addToList();
      },
      child: Text('Remove form the main screen'),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, this answer might help you to get my point well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74071768/11044929)

Comment: Can you further explain this? I dont quite understand how I am supposed to make this work to my project. See this how i call the custom method which inside calls showDialog() and returns the dialog:

```onPressed: () {
      blocController.add(LoadInvoiceToDialogScreen());
      invoiceDetailsDialog(
              context: context,
              screenWidth: screenWidth,screenHeight: screenHeight,
              blocController: blocController,);},
```

Code above on invoice page, trying to seperate to generalize the widget and reduce code in file.

Comment: thought i figured it out but turns out not. I had to disable rednering my form widget cuase it erros out.  and show dialog is now the entire screen size. I'll show the latest changes in my question

Comment: so new update fixed the previous problems. The dialog screen is now sized correctly and when displaying form widget the error has been resolved but I am still where i started. The bloc as before is being called successfuly but the showdialog or more specially the listview is not rebuilding for any event: when the user clicks the button for adding or deleting. I'll post updated code to question

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your dialog within the stateful builder and then you will get the method  to set your dialog state.

Comment: setstate()? I did use this before and it was working however it not keeping bloc archtecture plan. And when user submits they will need to be calls to the firebase API. would prefer to keep that all seperate. But I might return to it temp if it will work. Thanks for reminding about it, forgot I used that earlier.